# How to select max value FOR THE FIRST TIME of a column

Tags: r

I have a data look like:

```
power = seq(1:10)
Rsq = c(-0.503268561,-0.337920056,-0.000470763,0.204181075,0.299591119,0.376839371,0.424761718, 0.424487633, 0.642269314, 0.194640766)
df = data.frame(power,Rsq)
```

Now, I want to choose max value FOR THE FIRST TIME in the column 'Rsq'. From that, my expected result look like:

```
power ------- Rsq

7 ----------0.424761718
```

Comment: You're looking for what's called a local maximum.

Comment: Oh, due to my poor grasp of English skills, I don't even know this problem called a local maximum. Thanks @Reeza

Comment: If you search with the same term everyone else uses, you're more likely to find relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `diff`erence of adjacent elements in 'Rsq', check if it is less than 0 and get the index of the `max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    slice(which.max(c(diff(Rsq), NA) < 0))
#   power       Rsq
#1     7 0.4247617
```

Answer (score 0):

In Base-R

```
  df[which.max(df$Rsq),]

  power       Rsq
7     7 0.4247617
```

Comment: No, your solution will result in the power of 9 with Rsq of 0.642269314 . Anyway, thanks !